# How to convert a address to specific type variable in GDB?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gcc, gdb

I got an address such as 0x7fc9e401a02a in my log file, and I know that this address is a pointer of type Connection.

Then I start GDB, what I wanna know is: how to convert this address to a temporary variable of type Connection*, and display relevant information of Connection*?

How to do this, any hints?

Comment: Try this: `print *(Connection*)0x7fc9e401a02a`.  This assumes that your address is from a core file that your looking at in gdb.  If that address is from a run of your code, it will certainly not exist without re-running the code inside gdb.

Comment: If object still exists on stack/heap and program is still running, just attach (attach PID) to process, and you should be able to do what JaredC writes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because my Connection class has a namespace, so what I should do is as bellow:

```
print * ('MyNameSpace::Connection' *) 0x7fc9e401a02a
```

Thanks JaredC and dbrank0 for your answers.